# How can I avoid duplicate code in the if-else chain?

Tags: apex

I have the following code snippet

`if(!setPass){
    this.teacher  = Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher
                    (sess, 'TestTeacher1', 
                    Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED,
                    Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
                    Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO);
}else{
    this.speaker  = Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher
                    (sess, 'TestTeacher1', 
                    Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED, 
                    Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
                    Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES);
}`

The only change in the else condition is Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES (in the if condition it is set to Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO), the rest is just being duplicated! How can I avoid this? Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this :

```
this.teacher   = Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher
                    (sess, 'TestTeacher1', 
                    Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED, 
                    Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
                    (setPass) ? Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES : Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 this.teacher  = Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher
                (sess, 'TestTeacher1', 
                Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED, 
                Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
                (!setPass)?Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES:Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure which language is this, but you can usually use

```
   public void main() {
       if(!setPass){
          this.teacher  = create(false);
       } else {
          this.speaker  = create(true);
       }
   }

   public Teacher create(boolean setPass) {
       return Ev_TeacherTestUtil.createTeacher
                    (sess, 'TestTeacher1', 
                    Ev_TeacherService.NOMINATED, 
                    Ev_TeacherService.EMPLOYEE_NO, 
                    setPass ? Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES : Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO);
   }
```

In other words, single line if statement, should solve this.

```
setPass ? Ev_TeacherService.PASS_YES : Ev_TeacherService.PASS_NO
```

Other option, is builder pattern

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern